# Calculating Differences between two rows MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am having trouble calculating differences between two rows.  The current query is as follow

```
Sessiontype Question    Average
Admission   Question 1  2.25
Discharge   Question 1  4.25
```

I need to calculate discharge average - admission average for question 1. Note this is just a snipplet of the query, there are actually 5 questions. So the problem is I am unsure how to approach it in MS Access .